# Express: req.params vs req.body (JSON)

Tags: node.js, rest, express

Which is more correct, and why? Does it depend on the scenario? Is there a standard?

```
router.post("/user", function(req, res) {
  let thisUserId = req.body.userId;
});

router.post("/user/:userId", function(req, res) {
  let thisUserId = req.params.userId;
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: what do you want to do inside the function?

Comment: @Kepotx create a user, in this example.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This question is more about RESTful API conventions than node or express. Based on generally accepted [REST conventions](https://restfulapi.net/resource-naming/), this is basic CRUD operation:

```
/* fetch all users */
GET /users 

/* fetch specific user */
GET /users/:userId

/* create new user */
POST /users 

/* edit specific user */
PUT /users/:userId

/* delete specific user */
DELETE /users/:userId
```

So in your case I would say `req.body` is more appropriate, considering you want to create a user.

**EDIT**: another useful resource that supports this case: [10 best practices for better RESTful API](https://blog.mwaysolutions.com/2014/06/05/10-best-practices-for-better-restful-api/).

Answer (score 7):

`req.body` is used to access actual form data that you 'posted'.

`req.params` is used for route parameters, in your case `userId` which is passed in the parameters:

```
router.post("/user/:userId", function(req, res) {
  let thisUserId = req.params.userId;
}
```

The official docs:

**req.body**

> Contains key-value pairs of data submitted in the request
>   body. By default, it is undefined, and is populated when you use
>   body-parsing middleware such as body-parser and multer.

[Link to req.body docs](http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#req.body)

**req.params**

> This property is an object containing properties mapped to
>   the named route “parameters”. For example, if you have the route
>   /user/:name, then the “name” property is available as req.params.name.
>   This object defaults to {}.

[Link to req.params docs](http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#req.params)

If you want to implement guards or any other logic in your route that relies on that id (of an existing user), you pass the userID in the params.

Let's say you are submitting a form where a new user registers.. You don't want to send the credentials in the parameters since it's confidential data and easily accessible this way. Here it makes sense to put those values in the request-body and use therefore `req.body`..

As Haris Bouchlis already mentioned in his answer it depends on your CRUD-ops that you like to perform.

Comment: This doesn't really answer my question which is *why*? Why would I choose one over the other? Thanks.

Comment: @chrisheseltine Let's say you submit a form where a new user registers.. You don't want to send the credentials in the parameters since it's confidential data and easily accessible this ways. Here it makes sense to put those values in the request-body and use therefore `req.body`..

Comment: @chrisheseltine It's a pleasure - If you like you may want to accept my or Harris answer ;)

Answer (score 0):

In this case, I advise using `req.params.userId`.

General API entries have this standard. To get all the users, the path will be `/users`.
To retrieve or update a specific user, the path will be `/users/1`.

[API example](https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, they are completely different and used for different purposes:

**1** - `req.params` comes from path segments of the URL that match a parameter in the route definition such as `/song/:songid`. So, with a route using that designation and a URL such as `/song/48586`, then `req.params.songid === "48586"`.

**2** - `req.body` properties come from a form post where the form data (which is submitted in the body contents) has been parsed into properties of the body tag.